# style.display="none" not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

I am trying to do a simple if statement in javascript. The script will determine the visibility of a `div` based on the option selected in a `select`.

If I select any option, it will act like I selected "Custom" and display the `div`. But if I then select "This Month" or "Past Month", it will not return to `display="none"`. The interesting part is that the value of the text boxes, "fromDate" and "toDate", change as if the if statement fired correctly. I can't figure out why they won't return to `style.display="none"`.

```
<body>
<form name="input" action="mlic_DORReport.cfm?dlFile=1" method="post" style="text-align:center;">
    <table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h1>Electronic NOS File Generator</h1>
            <hr/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="99%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <cfoutput>
                    <input type="hidden" name="pastFromMonth" id="pastFromMonth" value="#pastFromMonthOp#"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="pastEndMonth" id="pastEndMonth" value="#pastEndMonthOp#"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="thisFromMonth" id="thisFromMonth" value="#thisFromMonthOp#"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="thisEndMonth" id="thisEndMonth" value="#thisEndMonthOp#"/>
                    </cfoutput>
                    <div id="customHeader" style="display:none">
                        <table align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" style="font-weight:bold;">
                                 Enter dates in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <table align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="65%">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <b>Date Range: </b>
                            <select name="frombox" id="fromBox" onchange="selectDateRange()">
                                <option value="Past Month">Past Month</option>
                                <option value="This Month">This Month</option>
                                <option value="Custom">Custom</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="customTxtBox" style="display:none">
                                <cfoutput>
                                <table align="center">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                         From:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="fromDate" id="fromDate" mask="YYYY-MM-DD" value="#pastFromMonthOp#"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                         To:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="toDate" id="toDate" mask="YYYY-MM-DD" value="#pastEndMonthOp#"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                                </cfoutput>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <b>DMV #: </b>
                            <select name="txtDmvNumber"/>
                                <option value="D1111">D1111</option>
                                <option value="D2222">D2222</option>
                                <option value="D3333">D3333</option>
                                <option value="D4444">D4444</option>
                                <option value="D5555">D5555</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                     &nbsp
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="customFooter" style="display:none">
                        <table align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">
                                 (Note: The HH:MM:SS section of the "From:" date should be
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">
                                 entered 00:00:00 and the "To:" date should be entered 23:59:59)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

JS

```
function selectDateRange() {
    var fromboxOption = document.getElementById("fromBox").options[document.getElementById("fromBox").selectedIndex].text;

    if (fromboxOption == "Past Month") {
        document.getElementById("fromDate").value = document.getElementById("pastFromMonth").value;
        document.getElementById("toDate").value = document.getElementById("pastEndMonth").value;

        document.getElementById("customHeader").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("customTxtBox").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("customFooter").style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (fromboxOption == "This Month") {
        document.getElementById("fromDate").value = document.getElementById("thisFromMonth").value;
        document.getElementById("toDate").value = document.getElementById("thisEndMonth").value;

        document.getElementById("customHeader").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("customTxtBox").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("customFooter").style.display = "none";
    }
    else(fromboxOption == "Custom") {
        document.getElementById("customHeader").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("customTxtBox").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("customFooter").style.display = "inline";
    }
}
    </body>
```

Comment: have you checked error console for some errors ?

Comment: well the dates gets set before the styles so the dates should work regardless. What happens when This/Past month gets selected? does the header/footer disappear or does it not disappear?

Comment: The values are set just as an initial place holder so that if they submit the form with the default "Past Month" selected it won't be left blank. They do not disappear but the script changes the value of the textboxes "fromDate" and "toDate" which is only fired if the user changes their selection from the select tag. The values that the textboxes are changed to are correct as well. Its almost as if everything works perfectly until it reaches the style selections within the if statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the last condition of your `if` statement you included an expression without an 'if'. Change it from

```
else (fromboxOption == "Custom")
```

to

```
else if (fromboxOption == "Custom")
```

Comment: I swear I tried that before but for some reason it worked. Can't believe it was that easy of a solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Technically, he should be able to keep it as `else`. But for some reason it wasn't working